# joins in sql. User details based on Cancellation

Tags: mysql

Write query to display user_id and user name of those who have canceled their tickets and display records in ascending order by user_id. 
my code:

```
SELECT u.user_id, name
FROM users u JOIN tickets t
ON u.user_id= t.user_id JOIN
cancellation c
ON t.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
WHERE cancellation_id IN 'cancel'
ORDER BY user_id;
```

this does not show any output

Comment: Maybe try `.. where cancellation_id = 'cancel'`

Comment: Please add some rows of your table and the output you are expecting the sql to produce from them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The type of join and the order of joins matters. See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for a clear explanation. Try this instead:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name
FROM cancellation c JOIN tickets t
ON t.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
JOIN users u ON u.user_id= t.user_id
WHERE cancellation_id is not null
ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: 'It does not work' is not something anyone can debug for you. Please add some sample data and required output to the question as requested above, that will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.user_id, u.name 
from users u join tickets t 
on u.user_id=t.user_id
join cancellation c on t.ticket_id=c.ticket_id 
order by u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work

```
select u.user_id,u.name
    from((users u inner join tickets t
    on u.user_id=t.user_id)
    inner join cancellation c
    on t.ticket_id=c.ticket_id)
    where cancellation_id is not null
    group by u.user_id,u.name
    order by u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.user_id,users.name
    from users join tickets 
    ON users.user_id = tickets.user_id
    join cancellation on
    tickets.ticket_id = cancellation.ticket_id
    where cancellation_id is not null
    order by user_id
```

Comment: please take some time to explain how this solves the problem so that other with similar problem can know the issue clearly.

Comment: The procedure for code-only answers brought before the review queue is the user is notified and given enough time to improve their own answer, by providing at least a sentence or two on what this code is doing and how it answers the question.  If the code is improved, it is saved, otherwise when it comes up for review much later, then it's low effort, low energy low quality and subject to deletion. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery

```
select 
    u.user_id,
    u.name
    from users u
    where user_id in 
    (select 
    user_id from tickets
    inner join cancellation on tickets.ticket_id
     = cancellation.ticket_id)
    order by user_id asc;
```